# Vagrant or Docker for environment development

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, development-environment

in our compagny we want to prepare an environment development for our internships so that they don't waste time to install all the tools that they're going to use (Wamp server, IDE's, different navigators, java ...).

We also want these development envrionments to be instances so that for example we can access wamp services in the virtual machine from the navigator that runs on the real os of the machine.

What's the best choice to do this Vagrant or Docker? How can we prepare this solution? 
A tutorial link will be very helpfull, Thanks.

Comment: Both docker & vagrant can serve the usecase. Your choice would depend on fine grained needs

Comment: Vagrant seems to be a better solution in your use case. Note that Docker is intended as lightweight containers that each serves a single process. Vagrant machines are complete virtual machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use both

Our host is Windows, we use vagrant to up a VM and in that VM we install docker then we can run docker containers therein, mapping ports from host to VM then VM to container, allowing container access from host

In my GitHub repo danday74 I have a repo called vagrant-docker-skelly ... Ignore everything else in that repo except the vagrant file ... Use this vagrantfile to up a VM with docker installed

All the best

Comment: just a further note, if u have windows pro you can install docker for windows, no need for vagrant, you only need vagrant on Windows Home, I always buy Windows pro now solely for this reason

Answer (score 0):

I use vagrant for my local development. I put my working directory on a github private repo and the vagrant config files to another called [Vagrantlife](https://github.com/Honpray/Vagrantlife) so that I push or pull each time I finish or start the work, either at home or on a new machine, as long as there are Vagrant and Virtualbox installed.

And I did some research on docker which end up some experienced developers saying docker doesn't have a good support on all platforms which is also mentioned in the document in Vagrant.